# Fluid being absorbed by a plane (cloth)

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, dynamic-paint

I want to make an animation similar to the gif, i want a drop (of water) to fall and to be absorbed by the cloth. 
I have the cloth texture and a fluid simulation with dynamic paint that creates the wet cloth, but i don't know how to make the fluid geometry to be absorbed smoothly by the cloth.

Thank you!

[image: Reference]